# Magento 2.3.4 - Multie store 503 Service Unvailable

Tags: multistore, magento2.3.4, multi-website

I tried to create a second website.

1.Created website

```
code: base_new
```

2.Created store

```
code: store_new
```

3.Create store view

```
code: newstorename
```

4.Configuration > Web > Add Store Code to Urls

```
Set to YES
```

5.Changed scope to `store_new`

6.Changed Base Url in that scope from http://www.myshop.com/ to http://www.myshop.com/newstorename/ (also tried https://www.myshop.com/store_new/)

7.Clear cache, flushed cache, reindex.

But I keep getting **503 Service Unavailable** notices.
Due to the Add Store Code Url settings the main website is now also under a code https://www.myshop.com/mainwebsite/ there I also get a 503 warning...however..if I go to a category page https://www.myshop.com/mainwebsite/category.html there isn't any problem and the page shows up.

Comment: did you check the log? var/log

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a folder for the new website on root folder?